# How can I refer to content of tag defined with in the current xml?

Tags: xml

Is it possible to refer to the content of a tag defined with in the current XML ?

For example, with the following in xml:

```
<Scheduler>
<Faculty_Roster>
    <Faculty>foo</Faculty>
    <Faculty>bar</Faculty>
</Faculty_Roster>
<Subjects>
    <Subject>
        <Name>Fakeology</Name>
        <Semester>1</Semester>
    </Subject>
    <Subject>
        <Name>Onionology</Name>
        <Semester>2</Semester>
    </Subject>
<Sections>
    <Section>C</Section>
    <Section>X</Section>
</Sections>
```

I would like to create the following type of XML mapping between faculty, subjects and sections [with what I need in square brackets] :

```
<Subject_Faculty_Collection>
 <Subject_Faculty_Sec>
    <Subject_Name>@Subjects/Subject/Name:1 [refer to the first entry] [Instead of Fakeology]</Subject_Name>
    <Faculty_Name>@Faculty_Roster/Faculty:1 [ instead of foo]</Faculty_Name>
    <Section_Name>@Sections/Section:1 [instead of C] </Section_Name>
 <Subject_Faculty_Sec>
```

I would like to do this to avoid duplication. Is it possible ? If not, is there a design flaw here ?

Comment: Parse the xml and create arrays for faculty, subjects and sections. Then loop through them and create output as the xml you require. Array indices can be used to get the ordering numbers

Comment: Hi Abhishek, the problem is that the subject-faculty mapping is part of input and not something I can decide in program.

Comment: Instead of arrays store them in hashmaps. The faculty, subject, etc. Will be keys, and the order of reading them will be the values. Then loop through whatever is the main ordering and print corresponding info according to the input. Hope that helps.